# list of all combinations

Tags: list, scala

I am currently struggling with a combinations problem. I have, as initial input, a list of lists of tuples, in other words the following:

```
List[List[(Char, Int)]]
List(List('k', 2), List('r', 2))
```

Given the input above, or any combination of char and int, I am supposed to return the following:

```
List(List(),List(('k', 1)),List(('k', 2)),List(('r', 1)),List(('k', 1), ('r', 1)),
     List(('k', 2), ('r', 1)), List(('r', 2)), List(('k', 1), ('r', 2)), 
     List(('k', 2), ('r', 2))
)
```

Using Scala's For I've isolated the characters and integers into to lists

```
List(List(), List(1), List(2), List(1, 2))
List(List(), List(k), List(r), List(k, r))
```

But I am stuck on how to combine both lists to get the list of all subsets above. I have tried

```
lettersets map (i => numsets flatMap (j => i zip j))
```

However this returns the following incomplete and incorrect result:

```
List(
     List(), List((k,1), (k,2), (k,1)), List((r,1), (r,2), (r,1)), 
     List((k,1), (k,2), (r,1), (r,2))
    )
```

Can anyone help me improve my approach, or show me why this won't work and suggest a better approach, so I can get the remaining combinations.?(

```
List(('a', 1), ('b', 2))
List(('a', 2), ('b', 2))
```

P.S. the input list is not limited to just two elements, it should be able to work for all N elements of the original list. Finally, I don't really want the solution itself, just suggestions of other things to try or an improvement to my map of maps one liner.

Thank you all for the help and tips.

Comment: It seems to me that the algorithm of constructing power set will be useful for you

Comment: however please note that List(List('k', 2), List('r', 2)) is not a List[List[(Char,Int)]] it should be List(List(('k',2)),List(('r',2)))

Comment: Sorry Guys forgot to mention that the type of the output is:
List[List[(Char, Int)]]

Comment: This question is extremely similar to the week 6 programming assignment in [Functional Programming Principles in Scala](https://www.coursera.org/learn/progfun1/), specifically `def combinations`.  The only difference is that you replaced 'a' and 'b' with 'k' and 'r' (although you forgot the second code block).  :(

Answer (score 4):

I got the answer thank you @Poindextrose for the hint it lead me to the right answer. This is my solution

```
  def combinations(occurrences: Occurrences): List[Occurrences] = occurrences match {
    case List() => List(Nil)
    case (c, n) :: others =>
       val tails = combinations(others)
       tails ::: (for {
            j <- tails
            i <- 1 to n
          } yield (c, i) :: j)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(for {
  p <- input
  i <- 1 to p._2
} yield (p._1, i)).toSet.subsets.map(_.toList).toList
  .filter(l =>  l.map(_._1).toSet.size == l.size)
```

Where **input** is *List(List('k', 2), List('r', 2))*